# whether the preposition is needed or not

Tags: prepositions

> My house is situated at just 50 kilometers southeast of the town.

I'd like to know whether the preposition "at" should be placed after "situated" or not. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If the location is somewhere along a line or at a precise coordinate in two or three-dimensional space, we would use **at**:

**Underwater pressure *at* 60 meters....**

**My car is broken down on the side of the road *at* mile-marker 217.**

**Hey Bob, can you hear me OK? You sound like you're in an echo chamber. I'm standing here *at* storage unit J6. The door is busted open.**

But when the location is only vaguely indicated, e.g. somewhere on the perimeter of a circle, then we would not use **at**:

**My house is situated just 50km southeast of the town.**

Answer (score 3):

I would not use "at". If you say

> 50 kilometers southeast of the town

That isn't a very precise location. They wouldn't know *exactly* where you live. I would use *at* if you are giving very exact locations, for example:

> Meet me at the vending machine on the second floor.
>
> I'll be at the old blue house on the corner of 7th and main street.
>
> I'll see you at 7:30.

I realize the last one is a time, not a place, but the idea still stands. It's an exact time.